# Serializing look up object for App Fabric

Tags: appfabric, serializable

I have to cache a set of lookup collection based on several objects. In other to use app fabric, the underlying object has to be serializable. My issue is that I have over 100 object that could potentially be cached and going and marking each of them with the [serializable] attribute just seems wrong to me. Since all of this object derive from a base class, I would think marking the base class as serializable would make the derived class serializable but attributes do not work with inheritance. Does enyone know how to go about making all these classes serializable without marking each of them with the property ? Can I make all classes in a namespace serializble for instance, in which case I can put all of them in a library.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you're using the Azure version of AppFabric then you will just have to make the classes serializable, as [`IDataCacheObjectSerializer`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/azure/hh552969.aspx) never made it into the Windows Server version of AppFabric.